# Category links in menu don't work when switching language

Tags: magento2, multistore, view

So basically I added a new view store (for language purposes), and when selecting a single product from the home page, it redirect correctly to that product, but if I use my mega menu to for example click on "Men's Watches", it gives me an error like this

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.catalogsearch_fulltext_scope3' doesn't exist, query was...

Any idea ?

Comment: This is not a standard table of Magento. Are you sure you don't have any custom extension that affects this? even if you do, try rebuilding all indexes.

Comment: Using magento 2 btw , and no i didn't add any extensions that I'm aware of, only using a theme. Rebuilding indexes with cron job?

Comment: Rebuilding indexes didn't do anything, and when i switch back to my default english store, everything works, when i switch back to french, clicking the categories doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a known issue with php7

https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/39

otherwise the table creation is triggered by creating the store view (\Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Store\Save), there must be something around Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Store not being called (store_add observer).